# Unity Android Plugin Handle Incoming intent

Tags: android, android-intent, unity-game-engine

I've been trying to make a unity plugin that will pass a string to another specific app using the ACTION_SEND intent. I'm making the other app that receives the string too I can open the receiver but I'm having trouble receiving the string.

I followed this to make the handling code below
http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html

Both these function are in my Class which extends com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity. None of the logs seems to appear in logcat.

Edit: Using logcat a bit more the receiver's onCreate() is called but the getIntent() line returns the main launcher activity rather than the send action

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get intent, action and MIME type
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) 
    {
        Log.v("VM","ACTION INTENT");
        if ("text/plain".equals(type)) 
        {
            Log.v("VM","HANDLE TEXT : " + intent);
            handleSendText(intent); // Handle text being sent
        } 
    } 
}

void handleSendText(Intent intent) 
{
    Log.v("VM","intent : " +  intent);
    String sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
    if (sharedText != null) 
    {
        Log.v("VM","Handling Text : " +  sharedText);
        // Update UI to reflect text being shared
        UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("JavaCallback", "HandleText", sharedText);
    }
}
```

Comment: Managed to get it. The manifest had forwardtodalvik set to true switched it to false. It works Although only if the app isn't open already.